# How to display selected value from the drop down menu in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am a Rails newbie. I have created a drop down using collection_select and grouped_collection_select. My issue is that I am not able to display the selected option value from the drop down list. I have to display only the selected value on a new page but I am not able to get it.

Comment: Use model object and assign value manually to column you want to display as selected on new form.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `:selected => params[:name_of_form][:name_of_field]`

```
= f.select :category, 
           options_for_select(['option', 'value']... etc ), 
           :selected => params[:user][:category]
```

I cant remember if the symbol goes on the inside like above, or if it

You should really be more clear when you are asking questions on SO, and you should also include code.

ALWAYS ALWAYS ALWAYS INCLUDE CODE!